# Unity Lens not working

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

I cant get the work. I have installed some unity lens such as the youtube one, askubuntu, torrent, music etc, but they don't work.

When I type anything nothing appears. I have tried to un-install them and re-install and to reset unity but didn't help.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

After installing a lens you must log out and back in before it works.

Comment: or simple run `unity --replace`

Comment: I installed them few days ago. Its not because of that

Comment: The askubuntu lens is installed in /opt/unity-lens-askubuntu. Try opening a terminal, cd to that folder, and executing ./unity-askubuntu-daemon on the command line. it will give you an error message if it can't start that may help you correct your problem. In my case since it was already running it told me that instaed of starting another instance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved with

```
rm ~/.cache/software-center
rm -rf ~/.local/share/zeitgeist
zeitgeist-daemon --replace
```

restart

source:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1911109&page=2